# Returning a object with functions in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I'm using a COM interface to get some kind of technical sub structures from 3rd part program but before that i'm listing how many substructures in the model after that i'd like to assign that to my `Substr` parameter.

```
Private Shared Function checkListSubSubstrs(ByVal Substrs As IScrNamedObjectList)
    Dim Substr As IScrSubstructure
    Dim nSubstr As Integer
    nSubstr = Substrs.count
    For i As Integer = 0 To nSubstr - 1
        Substr = Substrs.item(i)
    Next
    Return Substr
End Function
```

How can i get the Substr object because if i'm using like that  (above code structure) visual studio warns me like below;

> "Variable '`Substr`' is used before it has benn assigned a value. A null
>   reference exception could result at runtime"

Comment: This is just a warning that substr MIGHT be null. It isn't an error. Is your code working as expected? You can prevent this warning by declaring 'Dim Substr As IScrSubstructure=Nothing'

Comment: You should also turn `Option Strict On`, which will prevent you doing silly things like not declaring the return type of a function.

Comment: Also, your code doesn't really make sense as it is.  You loop through your list and assign each item to the same variable, then return that variable when the loop is done.  That's just going to return the last item in the list every time.  If you only want the last one then why loop and if you want them all, that code needs to change.  Also, `Substr` isn't a parameter.  It's a local variable.  `Substrs` is the parameter.

Comment: @jmcilhinney yes you're right it seems wrong i want all of my items in the list. I'd change somehow to correct way i think.

Comment: I'm afraid that you are not really making sense.  You're passing in a list of items and you want to get the items back but the only way you can get multiple items back is in a list of some sort, so what exactly does that method achieve?  Maybe you want an `IScrSubstructure` array or a `List(Of IScrSubstructure)` instead of the `IScrNamedObjectList` COM interface. In that case, you'd need to create that array or collection in the method, populate it and return it.

Comment: @jmcilhinney i'd like to get list of substructure objects after that i want to get each of substructures's another property. so i need to return each of object at list.

Comment: So, are you saying that you want that method to return a list containing a property value from each item in the list that you pass in?

Comment: @jmcilhinney hmm yes. i will use that object in another function/sub procedure to get their properties but as you said with that for loop i only get the last object in the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what I understand your question to be, you would do something like this:

```
Private Shared Function GetSomePropertyValues(substructures As IScrNamedObjectList) As SomeType()
    Dim values As New List(Of SomeType)

    For i = 0 To substructures.Count - 1
        value.Add(substructures.Item(i).SomeProperty)
    Next

    Return values.ToArray()
End Function
```

You might also be able to use LINQ, although I'm not 100% sure with COM interfaces.  You could try something like this:

```
Private Shared Function GetSomePropertyValues(substructures As IScrNamedObjectList) As SomeType()
    Return substructures.Cast(Of IScrSubstructure)().
                         Select(Function(s) s.SomeProperty).
                         ToArray()
End Function
```